# Explanation for this no flux boundary code needed

Tags: python

Im completely incompetent in programming! Can anyone help me understand what this code does exactly?

According to the notes, it should impose a no-flux boundary condition, but im completely baffled at what the terms indicate. Can anyone explain this to me?

```
    for Z in (U, V):
        Z[0,:] = Z[1,:]
        Z[-1,:] = Z[-2,:]
        Z[:,0] = Z[:,1]
        Z[:,-1] = Z[:,-2]
```

Answer (score 1):

`Z`, as a 2d list, is seemingly the grid representing the discrete state space of your problem. This snippet simply initializes the values corresponding to the boundary rows and columns of the grid as follows:

`Z[0,:] = Z[1,:]`: initialize the leftmost column by the values of its next column;

`Z[-1,:] = Z[-2,:]`: initialize the rightmost column by the values of its previous column;

`Z[:,0] = Z[:,1]`: initialize the top row by the values of its immediate lower row;

`Z[:,-1] = Z[:,-2]`: initialize the bottom row by the values of its immediate upper row.

Comment: Do you know how I can allow flux at the boundaries by manipulating the codes?

Comment: That depends on what you exactly mean by flux. Any mathematical definition may be implemented.